# I have a question about focus, z-index, and their relation to scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, focus, z-index

Visit here for an example: www.davepoyzer.com

My problem is, the top div (#topheader) sits above (via z-index) the scrolling div (#content). If you try scrolling with your mouse while the cursor is over #topheader, it wont scroll #content, which is below it. Is their anyway to fix this with javascript (the page already entirely relies on javascript)? I was thinking changing focus might do it, but I'm not very knowledgeable on focus.

Here's an idea, but I don't know if it's possible. Basically, when mouse is scrolled over one div (#topheader), it would be capture with javascript and scroll a different div (#content). Is this possible?

The current CSS is as is because of several different factors. I really don't think changing the CSS is going to work. For example, you can't click on the nav links if you put #topheader under #content.

Any ideas or suggestions would be awesome! Thanks for reading!

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure if this would work or not - but make the #topheader a child of #content.  Therefore, event bubbling would trigger the scroll event to your #content.  I was thinking about transferring the focus to your #content div... wasn't quite sure of a clean solution to that yet.

Comment: @johnstrickler It does work accept is removes a different functionality. I am attempting to keep #topheader centered with position:fixed or keeping it outside of #content and using position: absolute

Comment: @johnstrickler is their anyway to make links work through a div? When #topheader is underneath #content you can't click on the links, is their a way to make them clickable?

Comment: @Dave You could probably simulate a click but I wouldn't recommend it.  You'd have to calculate the event click's position then somehow simulate that to the div below to find the anchor.  I'm going to post an answer that I think you'll like.

Comment: @johnstrickler Yeah, that'd be getting ugly, haha. I did just find this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel (playing with it now, gotta figure out how it works)

Comment: @Dave I saw the same thing which I was playing with for some of my apps.  Let me know if you get it going!

Comment: @johnstrickler I have this code that is catching the wheel scroll but isnt doing any scrolling, can you help me fix the code to work? $("#topheader").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
     $("#content").scrollTop -= (delta * 30);
  event.preventDefault();
 });

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could bind code to the scroll event of the header and the code will scroll the content div. Here is a jQuery reference.
http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: I'm thinking .scroll() wouldn't work because I can't trigger .scroll() if it's not scrolling. Make sense? I think I need to hook to some sort of mouse wheel function.